# Does Fargate need HA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, high-availability, aws-fargate

I have an auto scaling ECS cluster backed by fargate. The lower bound is 1 instance. Would i need to worry about HA? Lets say an AZ crashes, wouldnt the cluster logic spawn it in another AZ, does this imply that among other benefits, Fargate cuts out the HA/redundancy cost as well, with some service degrade of course

Answer (score 1):

Only if you run your ECS service in vpc with subnets in more then one AZ. If you just run a single ECS task (not ECS service), you will not have HA.